# TCP application setting Don't Fragment (DF) Bit

Tags: tcp, icmp, mtu

I noticed that some TCP application is setting the DF (Don't Fragment) bit. My research seems to indicate that TCP wants to avoid fragmentation and instead want to adjust the segment size (MSS).

However, my understanding is this mechanism requires the use of ICMP Too-Big packet. nowadays many people uses NAT and FW and they often block all unsolicited ICMP packet. How would MSS adjustment work in these very common environments then? Or are these gateways smart enough to parse inside the ICMP and match existing session?

Comment: If all ICMP is dropped, then it should be expected that the functions that are mediated by ICMP are lost.  This includes MTU discovery.  Firewalls will inspect unreachables and match existing rules and permit, and so while it is common to block all ICMP, it should not be considered the correct approach.

Comment: ICMP doesn't use TCP.

Comment: @DavidPostill No one's saying ICMP uses TCP. OP's talking about how some ICMP messages contain a copy of the headers of the packet that caused the error. He's right that NATs and SPI firewalls have to parse the TCP headers inside those ICMP packets.

Answer (score 2):

You're describing an algorithm called "Path MTU Discovery". It's a default feature of all modern OS networking stacks (so it's generally the TCP/IP stack that does this, not the apps) and it works most of the time. Only ignorant sysadmins and buggy products block all ICMP messages. Even sites that choose to block ICMP Echoes (pings) are usually smart enough to still let ICMP Destination Unreachable messages through.

And yes, good NAT gateway and SPI firewall implementations look at the captured headers inside the ICMP Destination Unreachable message to figure out which flow it matches and handle it appropriately.

Comment: I am wondering why the answer does not say the important information: **Enabled PMTUD causes the outgoing packets to have the DF flag set.** Probably on most of the systems PMUTD is enabled by default.

Comment: @pabouk OP said he saw the DF bit set, and in my answer I said that's because he's seeing PMTUD happening. To me, that communicates that PMTUD is the cause of the DF bit being set. Was that not clear and explicit enough? I guess I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at with your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately for me your answer was confusing. The OP is only partially describing PMTUD algorithm. OP is describing a possible effect of PMTUD. --- I was learning about causes for DF being set and from your answer I did not understand that enabling PMUTD causes (all) the outgoing TCP packets to have the DF flag set. It is not an application causing this. (as suggested in the question title)

Comment: @pabouk Oh I see, you wanted me to explicitly clear up OP's misconception that it was the app that was doing it. Okay, I've edited my answer to make that clear.